# Can someone translate this Targum Jonathan on Ezekiel?

Tags: halacha, history, tanach, nevua-prophecy, third-temple

Can someone translate this Targum Jonathan on Ezekiel 40:5?

וְהָא שׁוּרָא מִבָּרָא לְבֵיתָא סְחוֹר סְחוֹר וּבְיַד גַבְרָא קְנֵי מְשַׁחְתָּא דְחַד מִנְהוֹן שִׁית אַמִין בְּאַמְתָא דְהִיא אַמָה וּפְשַׁךְ וּמְשַׁח יַת פּוּתְיָא דְבִנְיָנָא קַנְיָא חַד וְרוּמָא קַנְיָא חַד

https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.40.5?lang=bi&p2=Ezekiel.40.5&ven2=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang2=bi&p3=Rashi_on_Ezekiel.40.5.1&lang3=bi&p4=Targum_Jonathan_on_Ezekiel.40.5&lang4=bi&w4=all&lang5=en

Comment: Why specifically Targum Jonathan on that verse? What problem(s) do you have with translating the Targum Jonathan on that verse, that you don't have with those on other verses? (The answer to this should be part of your question.)

Answer (score 1):

And behold, a wall outside the house, surrounding it, and in the man’s hand is a measuring stick, the size of six [average sized - Rashi] cubits - each cubit the size of a [smaller type of] cubit (five handbreadths -Rashi), plus another handbreadth - and he measured the width of the building, which came out to be the same size as the stick, and the same went for the hight